# How to set limit value beyond or lower than scale in ggplot2 R plots?

Tags: r, ggplot2

```
This is what the sample looks like: 

          lon      lat coefhouse_area
1790 139.6479 35.68921       40198.10
2338 139.7486 35.72688       48898.88
5586 139.7917 35.70118       51894.27
1781 139.7764 35.72445       37183.73
7175 139.7327 35.68729       61953.51
5114 139.6728 35.71694       31774.12
740  139.6732 35.76773       21838.05
1144 139.6612 35.67521       51955.33
7894 139.6881 35.68650       61959.34
3160 139.6978 35.76845       24545.57
```

```
mydata <- structure(list(lon = c(139.6478611111, 139.7485958333, 139.7917116667,139.776365, 139.7327444444, 139.6727777778, 139.6732202778, 139.6611527778,139.6881197222, 139.6978313889), lat = c(35.6892138889, 35.7268769444,35.7011827778, 35.724455, 35.6872947222, 35.7169444444, 35.7677344444,35.6752111111, 35.6864975, 35.7684458333), coefhouse_area = c(40198.0967049332,48898.8807986989, 51894.2653229301, 37183.7256682956, 61953.5107242126,31774.1181240253, 21838.0524357505, 51955.3266671361, 61959.3410634942,24545.5728813975)), row.names = c(1790L, 2338L, 5586L, 1781L,7175L, 5114L, 740L, 1144L, 7894L, 3160L), class = "data.frame")
```

I tried to plot the following:

```
plot<-ggplot(mydata, aes(x=lon,y=lat))+geom_point(aes(colour=coefhouse_area))+scale_colour_gradient2(low = "red", mid = "white", high = "blue", midpoint = 0, limits = c(20000, 50000), space = "rgb", na.value = "grey10", guide = "colourbar", guide_legend(title="Coefs"))
print(plot)
```

[image]

Now, I can limit the scale of value between 20000-50000(beyond or lower become black points), however, I want to set

gray points = beyond scale (value >50000) and

black points = lower than scale (value <20000) or something like that.
And display it on the legend as well.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2):

Create another variable using `cut` and then add that variable the colour aesthetics for geom_point, while reverting the continuous variable to fill.

```
mydata$group <- cut(mydata$coefhouse_area, 
                    breaks=c(0, 20000, 50000, Inf), 
                    labels=c("< 20000", "20000-50000", "> 50000"))


ggplot(mydata, aes(x=lon,y=lat)) +
  geom_point(aes(colour=group, fill=coefhouse_area)) +
  scale_colour_manual(values=c("black", "gray")) + 
  scale_fill_gradient2(low = "red", mid = "white", high = "blue", 
                       midpoint = 0, limits = c(20000, 50000), 
                       space = "rgb", na.value = "grey10", 
                       guide = "colourbar", guide_legend(title="Coefs"))
```

[image]